# oracle window functions

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

Could someone help me out with this query:

```
SELECT SUM(summa), name, 
       TO_CHAR(invoice_date, 'YYYY/mm') 
           OVER (PARTITON EXTRACT(MONTH FROM i.invoice_date, c.name) 
FROM invoice i, customer c 
WHERE i.customer_id = c.id
AND months_between(sysdate, invoice_date) = 3
AND rownum < 11 GROUP BY invoice_date, name
ORDER BY SUM(SUMMA) DESC;
```

Supposed to get the first ten rows from last three months, grouped by month and ordered by sum.

Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for help with...also a demo of your data you are querying from might be helpful as well.

Comment: You have unmatched parentheses, invalid syntax, misspelt keywords...

Comment: I don't know much about oracle, but `OVER()` applied to a non-aggregate seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, use proper explicit `join` syntax.  Second, you need `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT SUM(summa) as sumsumma, name, 
             TO_CHAR(invoice_date, 'YYYY/mm') as yyyymm,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(invoice_date, 'YYYY/mm')
                                ORDER BY SUM(summa) DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM invoice i JOIN
           customer c 
           ON i.customer_id = c.id
      WHERE months_between(sysdate, invoice_date) = 3
      GROUP BY invoice_date, name
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY sumsumma DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved it faster than I could generate test data. If it's not too much of a bother for you, maybe you could explain why the explicit join is needed?

Comment: @Novice . . . Explicit joins have been part of the ANSI standard for decades -- and supported by Oracle for almost as long.  They are more powerful, because they can express outer joins effectively.  Also, most people find the explicit `join` syntax easier to follow.